# How to specify in the script to only use a specific version of perl?

Tags: perl

I have a perl script written for version 5.6.1 and which has dependencies on Oracle packages, DBI packages and more stuff. Everything is correctly installed and works.

Recently perl version 5.8.4 got installed and because those dependencies are not correctly set so the script fails.

'perl' command points to /program/perl_v5.8.4/bin/perl -- latest version

So, when I have to run my perl script I have to manually specify in command prompt

```
 /program/perl_v5.6.1/bin/perl scriptName.pl
```

I tried adding following lines in script:

```
 /program/perl_v5.6.1/bin/perl 
 use v5.6.1;
```

But, this means script has to take Perl version > 5.6.1

I found couple of related question which suggested:

1. To export path. But, I want the script for all the users without have to export path
2. Specify version greater than. But, I want to use just one specific version for this script.
3. use/require commands. Same issue as above.

My question: How to specify in the script to only use a specific version of perl?

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood you, but couldn't you just specify the path to perl you need in `#!` line of your script? Like `#!/program/perl_v5.6.1/bin/perl`, for example.

Comment: I think he forgot the shebang in the shebang line.

Comment: @raina77ow Sinan is right I am having '#!/program/perl_v5.6.1/bin/perl' in my script. But it is still taking me to the latest perl installation (perl -version)

Comment: Erm... do you execute your script as `perl script.pl` - or just as `./script.pl`? Sorry if this sounds stupid (it probably does), just have to check. )

Comment: @raina77ow You are a life-saver! 


I was trying to run my script as 'perl scriptName.pl' and it was trying to run the script using latest perl installation(which was actually my stupid mistake). So, I had to specify whole perl installation path and run the script as ' /program/perl_v5.6.1/bin/perl scriptName.pl' Now when you suggested to run it as './scriptName.pl' It gave me permission denied and so Instead 

I tried running the script as 'scriptName.pl'. Works like a charm, picks up specified perl version 5.6.1 and gets job done. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll write this as an answer then; perhaps it'll save some other guy's life as well. )

Comment: "Recently perl version 5.8.4 got installed" - Are you posting from 2004? :-)

Comment: @DaveCross ha ha ... I know, right? :P Actually, this script is running on Solaris. For some reason, we have moved completely to Linux and stopped upgrading Perl versions on Solaris so its recent is still 5.8.4!

Comment: I can just about understand people using an ancient version of Perl that was installed on a box when it was new. But *upgrading* a system to a version of Perl that is eight years old seems a very strange concept to me :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the interpreter specified in the shebang line (`#!/some/path/to/perl`) is not used if perl script is called like this:

`perl some_script.pl`

... as the 'default' (to simplify) perl is chosen then. One should use the raw power of shebang instead, by executing the file itself:

`./some_script.pl`

Of course, that means this file should be made executable (with `chmod a+x`, for example).

Comment: The shebang isn't really ignored. It just doesn't use the interpreter from the shebang line if you've already specified one.

Comment: So if options are given there, they still will be used? Didn't know that actually, updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have in my code:

```
our $LEVEL = '5.10.1';
our $BRACKETLEVEL = sprintf "%d.%03d%03d", split/\./, $LEVEL;

if ($] != $currentperl::BRACKETLEVEL)
{
    die sprintf "Must use perl %s, this is %vd!\n", $LEVEL, $^V;
}
```

These are actually two different modules, but that's the basic idea.  I simply "use correctlevel" at the top of my script instead of `use 5.10.1;` and I get this die if a developer tries using the wrong level of perl for that product.  It does not, however, do anything else that `use 5.10.1;` would do (enable strict, enable features like say, switch, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Tanktalus. Issue was I was running the script as 'perl scriptName.pl' so it was taking me to latest perl installation. Now running the script as 'scriptName.pl' and it takes me to perl version mentioned in 'shebang' and 'use' commands.

Comment: It would be wise to put that whole thing in a `BEGIN{}` block, so that it fails quickly, at compile time.  Otherwise it's going to do all its `use()` statements (and other compile-time directives) first, before failing.

Comment: Actually, Ken, since this is in its own module (I hate cut&paste, makes more sense to put it in a module anyway), it is implicitly in a BEGIN already, as long as I `use` the module instead of `require`.  And if I `require` it, no `BEGIN` block is going to help.  I also put my `use correctlevel;` line near the top of relevant scripts.